# Input type "time" has no ":" on Nexus-One What can I do?

Tags: android

I have a layout with this statement

```
android:inputType="time"
```

I need to enter times such as 5:00 to show a count down timer as 5 minutes or 12:30:15 to show a start time hours, min, sec.

I don't particularly like making the user enter the ":" but I don't see a way to do a fixed format so I decided to live with it.  But it doesn't work on all my test phones.

It works fine on my Samsung tablet and my Nexus-4 but not on my Nexus-One.  I would like to be able to support as many platforms as possible.

Any ideas what I can do?  I thought about using a number picker but it needs API 11 and 2.3.5 is API 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you you make three EditTexts and 2 TextViews and arrange them like this and set them so that the cursor will advance from one to another.

[image: some EditTexts]

This uses more views, but in return you get a few things. It's harder for the user to enter something incorrect. It solves your issue with the colon in a manner that won't care about what device it's running on (or API lvl). You just have to manually insert the colons into your string when you pull the values out of the EditTexts.

I know I've filled out forms that include multiple boxes close to each other like this, so I wouldn't think it will be confusing to your users.

**EDIT:** You should be able to use `android:imeOptions` in your xml or `setImeOptions(int)`  in java to specify that you want the next button

Comment: This seems like a good idea.  Then I can use android:inputType="number"  which has the advantages you state.  I mocked it up and the only thing is that I was expecting the "Done" button to say "Next" so that the fields would advance by themselves.  Another of my pages works that way and I didn't do anything special to make that happen.  How do I do that?

Comment: I added android:nextFocusDown="@+id/textView4" and now I get the "Next" key.  I will change my app to use your suggestion.  Thank you.

Comment: Ahh cool, I edited with another way that you could set the button to be next too I think.